# Sending PHP Http response to client (mimic angular 2 response class format) according to Fetch standard

Tags: php, angular, fetch

I am using Angular 2 for my project. It use the `map` method to process the response from the server, I guess the response may have certain format (Fetch standard?) because I keep failing while sending data to the browser, the `map` just doesn't understand the response I sent.

I want to send: http status code, http status text, body

My angular 2 service code:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserAccountService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }
    create(user: UserAccount) {
        return this.http.post('/api/user', user, this.jwt()).map((response: Response) => response.json());
    }
    private jwt() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Component code:

```
export class RegisterComponent {
    constructor(private router: Router, private userAccountService: UserAccountService, private alertService: AlertService) { }
    register() {
        this.userAccountService.create(this.model)
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.alertService.success('Registration ok', true);
                    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                },
                error => {
                    this.alertService.error(error);
                    this.loading = false;
                }
            );
    }
}
```

My Php code:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 400 Please, try to display this error text');
```

It doesn't work (the angular apps does not recognize my status code and the error text), and try again.

```
header('HTTP/1.1 400 Please, try to display this error text');
echo json_encode(
    array(
        'status'=> 400,
        'statusText'=> 'blalakljafkjd;af fsaf',
        'url'=> 'fksdljfdsfds.com'
    )
    , JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
);
```

It fails too, and try again and again... still no success...

> In short, how to properly send a Http response according to Fetch Spec with Php? How should I format the header as well as the body?